# OpenGL version on mac

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am compiling a source code on my mac with nanogui. The defaut opengl version is 330 but when I out put the gl version, it tells me,its 2.1 and the glsl version is 120. I manually set the following right after glwfint()

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

But it still outputs gl version 2.1 and glsl version 1.2. and continue to tell me the GLSL language version is not supported. Is there any possibility that some other part of the code might change this setting so that the OpenGL sticks on its original mac version.

Comment: Check what OpenGL version your hardware supports at [Apple Mac's](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823)

Comment: try without glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

Answer (score 1):

Wrong OpenGL versions could be the result of graphics processors being prioritized in an undesired way.

Try checking `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER`. Does it return the name of your desired graphics processor?

#### Windows

**Nvidia**

Go to the "NVIDIA Control Panel" (*usually available in the context menu, if you right click on your desktop*). Then under "3D Settings" -> "Manage 3D Settings". Here you'll be presented with options to select your preferred graphics processor.

**AMD**

Go the the "Graphics Properties" (*usually available in the context menu, if you right click on your desktop*). Then under "Power" -> "PowerPlay" set the "Plugged In" and "Battery" to "Maximum Performance".

If the "Switchable Graphics Application Settings" is available, then you can also enforce "High Performance".

**Intel**

Go the the "(Intel) Graphics Properties" (*usually available in the context menu, if you right click on your desktop*). Then click the "3D" tab set the "General Settings" to "Performance". Now go back to the "Power" tab and set the "Graphics Power Plans" to "Maximum Performance".

After this go the control panel for your GPU.

#### Mac

Go to the "Energy Saver" and deselect the "Automatic graphics switching".

---

If the issue persists. First verify that the computer can actually find the desired graphics processor. Second check if there's any power saving settings enabled. Lastly also check if there's any driver updates.

---

**Resources**

- [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202043)
- [AMD Switchable Graphics](https://community.amd.com/docs/DOC-1581)
- [Instructions for Nvidia, AMD and Intel (Not Official)](https://communities.bentley.com/products/3d_imaging_and_point_cloud_software/w/wiki/25254/changing-graphics-card-settings-to-use-the-dedicated-gpu-on-a-windows-computer)

Comment: Thank you for answering. But there is no "Automatic graphics switching" in my Energy Saver. And these code works for other code which changes the opengl version to support even 4.1.  The code currently always use the version 210 and 120 no matter how I defined the glfwhintwindow, which bothered me several days.

Comment: Are you sure your Mac support versions newer than 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

> *This may be because your application is using legacy opengl profile instead of core profile.*

Please check your graphics hardware capabilities from OpenGL capabilities table

***Mac Capabilities*** : 
https://developer.apple.com/opengl/OpenGL-Capabilities-Tables.pdf

Let's assume your machine is Mac OS X 10.9 then below will be your machine capabilities.

- *OpenGL 2.1(Legacy), 3.3-4.1(Core)*
- *GLSL   1.2(Legacy), 3.3-4.1(Core)*

So, whenever your program uses legacy mode it will always give you **`OpenGL 2.1 / GLSL 1.2`**

**Solution**

Including GL3 libraries

> **Replace your code from  `#include <gl.h>` to  `#include <gl3.h>`**

Reference for API: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/api/GLES3/